# How to center an iframe horizontally?

Tags: html, css, iframe, alignment, center-align

Consider the following example: ([live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wYNSu/))

HTML:

```
<div>div</div>
<iframe></iframe>
```

CSS:

```
div, iframe {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #777;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Why the `iframe` is not centrally aligned like the `div`? How could I centrally align it?

Comment: why not wrap a div for this iframe?

Answer (score 489, accepted):

Add `display:block;` to your iframe css.

```css
div, iframe {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #777;
}

iframe {
    display: block;
    border-style:none;
}
```

```html
<div>div</div>
<iframe src="data:,iframe"></iframe>
```

Comment: So, alternately, you can give the container a `text-align: center` rule, correct?

Comment: yes adding text-align: center to the container would work too

Comment: I found I also had to add `margin: auto;`

Comment: `class="d-block mx-auto"` on my `<iframe>` satisfied (using bootstrap 4.0.0-beta.3)

Comment: I had a similar experience, needed this to get an iframe macro in Confluence to center properly: `style="border:1;display:block;margin:auto"`

Answer (score 82):

best way and more simple to center an iframe on your webpage is :

```
<p align="center"><iframe src="http://www.google.com/" width=500 height="500"></iframe></p>
```

where width and height will be the size of your iframe in your html page.

Comment: I thought the `align` attribute was deprecated? Why should the OP use this approach instead of using CSS - what's the advantage?

Comment: `style="text-align:center"` isn't deprecated and would do the same job

Comment: even though it is depreciated, this works, while everything else does not.

Comment: This works in the HTML file and thus is easier for newbs like me to impliment. I just did it in 2017 so it must not be depreciated. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: the align attribute has been removed in HTML5(although it works -though not on strict-HTML5 platforms like Wordpress or Github) and text-align does not work on iframes

Answer (score 22):

HTML:

```
<div id="all">
    <div class="sub">div</div>
    <iframe>ss</iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#all{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}
div.sub, iframe {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #777;

}
```

Answer (score 18):

The simplest code to align the iframe element:

```
<div align="center"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="www.youtube.com" frameborder="1px"></iframe></div>
```

Comment: Please see this first how-to-answer This question is answered before, obviously, you can add your answer here. But You Need to understand some points before answering. First, don't add an answer which is previously added with the same code or suggestion. Second, don't add an overly complicated answer if the user has asked very specifically about the problem and what he needs to solve this. Third, You can add a comment if you want to suggest anything regarding the answer or question.

Answer (score 14):

If you are putting a video in the iframe and you want your layout to be fluid, you should look at this webpage: [Fluid Width Video](http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php)

Depending on the video source and if you want to have old videos become responsive your tactics will need to change.

If this is your first video, here is a simple solution:

```html
<div class="videoWrapper">
    <!-- Copy & Pasted from YouTube -->
    <iframe width="560" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/n_dZNLr2cME?rel=0&hd=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

And add this css:

```css
.videoWrapper {
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
 padding-top: 25px;
 height: 0;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

Disclaimer: none of this is my code, but I've tested it and was happy with the results.

Answer (score 14):

My simplest solution to this.

```
iframe {
    margin:auto;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can put iframe inside a `<div>`

```
<div>
    <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

It works because it is now inside a block element.

Answer (score 5):

You can try

```
<h3 style="text-align:center;"><iframe src=""></iframe></h3>
```

I hope its useful for you

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/qsLp2ny5/)

Answer (score 5):

If you can't access the iFrame class then add below css to wrapper div.

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
    <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case solution was on iframe class adding:

```
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
```

Answer (score 3):

According to http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp, setting the left and right margins to auto specifies that they should split the available margin equally. The result is a centered element:

```
margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;
```

Comment: Only if the parent element has style text-align set to center.

Answer (score 2):

`<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FRishabh-Cars-Jodhpur-110479104559774&tabs=timeline&width=500&height=1200&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId" width="500" height="1200" style="border:none;overflow:hidden;display:block;margin:0 auto;" scrolling="yes" frameborder=".6" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share"></iframe>`

use it and embed facebook in iframe in center of html page

Comment: Thank you for sharing. The most important piece of information in your answer is to replace the default facebook page plugin style with your variation: `style="border:none;overflow:hidden;display:block;margin:0 auto;"`

Answer (score 0):

> Here I have put snippet for all of you who are suffering to make iframe or image in center of the screen horizontally. 
>   Give me THUMBS UP VOTE if you like.⯅.
>
> style > img & iframe > this is your tag name so change that if you're want any other tag in  center

```css
<html >
 <head> 
            <style type=text/css>
            div{}
            img{
                 margin: 0 auto;
          display:block;
          }
  iframe{ 
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:block;
  }
    
            </style>
</head>
 <body >
           
   <iframe src="https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/360/Big_Buck_Bunny_360_10s_1MB.mp4" width="320" height="180" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe> 
   
   <img src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/images/BigBuckBunny.jpg" width="320" height="180"  />
            </body> 
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
iframe {
    align-items: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```

to put the iframe div in the center, as well as to center the items inside the iframe.