# Showing iFrame horizontally centred

Tags: html

I have an iFrame in a php, i want to show it as centered horizontal atleast, Here is my code. How can i edit it to make it show center horizontal in browser

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<iframe src="https://<??>" width="850" target="_parent" height="850" scrolling="no" style="overflow:hidden; border:none;" style = "display:block;"></iframe>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: remove the extra style attributes, combine into one: `style="border:none; width:850px; margin: 20px auto;"`

Comment: **[old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366957/how-to-center-an-iframe-horizontally)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have two separate style tags. Be sure to merge them into one.
2. Try adding `margin: 0 auto;` to your style tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the iframe in a div then use css to center in the div like so:

```
<div class="myframe">
<iframe src="http://google.com" width="850" target="_parent"  height="850" scrolling="no"         border:none;></iframe>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.myframe
{
margin: 0px auto;
width: 850px;
}
</style>
```