# How do I display and centre align my responsive youtube videos properly?

Tags: html, css, video, youtube, embed

I'm trying to centrally align my responsive, embedded youtube videos and display them properly between the head and footer navigations. At the moment it will not display all 3 of the videos and they won't align properly. To see the whole entire code please visit this link: [my website video page](http://www.hgcarpentryandjoinery.com/mxjgtv/test.html)

Here is the main video coding I have tried:

```css
.video-container {
 position:relative;
 padding-bottom:56.25%;
 padding-top:30px;
 height:0;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.video-container iframe, .video-container object, .video-container embed {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:29.24%;
  height:auto;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <strong><br />
  <p></p>
  <div class="video-container"><iframe width="560" height="315"         
       src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/iydTzl6adLs" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
  <p></p>
  <div class="video-container"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fjZ5ZLWbu50" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
  <p></p>
  <div class="video-container"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/d8JOqV3Ql-w" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
  <p></p>
   </strong></center>
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366957/how-to-center-an-iframe-horizontally and you're not closing the `strong`-tag.

Comment: I tried adding "display:block" to the CSS code and it didn't change anything. Can you suggest anything else?

Answer (score 1):

you need to assign css property for the video containers.

```css
.video-container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.video-container iframe, .video-container object, .video-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <strong><br />
  <p></p>
  <div class="video-container"><iframe width="560" height="315"         
       src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/iydTzl6adLs" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
  <p></p>
  <div class="video-container"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fjZ5ZLWbu50" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
  <p></p>
  <div class="video-container"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/d8JOqV3Ql-w" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
  <p></p>
   </strong>
   
</center>
```

Comment: Tried the suggested CSS code and one video displayed at 100% width ( the video at the bottom of the code ) but it didn't displaty the whole height of the video.

Comment: Use height: 100% instead of height:auto, It will work

Comment: don't worry. I just figured out a way to get it all working.

Comment: in that case, please respond with the answer yourself or delete qour question... please do not leave questions open on SO