# How to center an iframe code for webpage?

Tags: html, iframe, alignment

Here is the code I want to have centered in the page element...right now it aligns itself to the left:

```
<iframe id="booking-iframe" sandbox="allow-top-navigation allow-scripts 
  allow-same-origin" style="width: 100%; height: 360px" frameborder="0" 
  src="https://booking.hospitable.com/widget/external/684862"></iframe>
```

Any help is appreciated...thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to center an iframe horizontally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366957/how-to-center-an-iframe-horizontally)

Comment: Are you referring to having the content inside the iframe central?

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a .

**Code:**

*HTML*

```
<div class="center">
   <iframe id="booking-iframe" sandbox="allow-top-navigation allow-scripts 
     allow-same-origin" style="width: 100%; height: 360px" frameborder="0" 
     src="https://booking.hospitable.com/widget/external/684862"></iframe>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
.center {
        text-align:center;
        width:100%;
}
```

Hope I helped :)

Comment: Thanks Nick..unfortunately, that didn't work. It's still oriented to the left of the iframe.

Comment: Thanks @Nick S..unfortunately that didn't work, it's still oriented to the left.